# Isn't Firebase phont auth very dangerous?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I realized this while implementing user re-sign in my app.

Since phone authentication is received from the client rather than from the server side, there is a phenomenon in which a hacker receives a firebase auth user with his mobile phone number and signs in by writing down someone else's mobile phone number to log in.

Every time you re-login, you need to write a new access token.

If he authenticates with his cell phone number and writes a new token with someone else's ID, it is very fatal. am I getting it wrong?

So I try to use identity platforms, but the documentation is not managed, and the rest API also has v1 and v3, and both do not work well.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: the scenario you describe is not possible with Firebase Authentication.

The UID of an account in Firebase Authentication is determined by the provider, not by the user themselves. The relationship between a UID and its credentials is determined when the account is first created, i.e. when you call one of the `createUser...` or when you call `verifyPhoneNumber` for the first time for a given number. There is no risk here, as this will be a new account owned by whatever credentials the user chose to enter.

After that account creation, the only way to associate more credentials with the account from the client-side SDKs is with the [`linkWith...` methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking), which can only be called *after* signing in with the credentials that were already associated with the account.

Comment: Ahh yah, in firebase auth, it works fine but in my mysql database server, they can decide account creation,(they actually call my rest api for creating) so order is phone authentication -> call my id creation api (it can be manipulated in arguments) (and refresh token and access token) so it is still dangerous, (I am talking about authentication and authorization when user account field is made with phone number)

Comment: There is no way for us to know about what your API does. My answer explains why the Firebase Authentication API doesn't have a security risk that you asked about. If that is now clear and you have questions about your own API implementation, I recommend posting a new question about that and including a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you're concerned about.